# how to get single column data from Dexiejs indexedDB table

Tags: javascript, arrays, dexie

how to get only price from each row

```
db -
    [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "name 2",
        "price": 40,
        "img": "img.jpeg",
        "isActive": true
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "name 2",
        "price": 60,
        "img": "img.jpeg",
        "isActive": true
    }]
```

currently with help of `db.product.toArray()` i am able to get all data.

but i want [40, 60] from Dexiejs indexedDB.

Answer (score 2):

If you index `price`, you can use [Collection.keys()](https://dexie.org/docs/Collection/Collection.keys()).

```
const db = new Dexie('yourDBName');
db.version(2).stores({
  product: 'id, price'
});

const prices = await db.product.orderBy('price').keys();
```

Comment: What if you don't care about the order?  Is there an equivalent way to get to keys() without the `orderBy`?

Comment: And is there an easy way to get both `id` and `price`?  I noticed that `keys()` returns *only* the index field. In my scenario I'd love to have primary key + index field only in an efficient query.

Comment: @Robert here is equivalent way to get keys() without orderBy: `db.product.offset(0).keys()`

Comment: IndexedDB doesn't have any built in prop selection except for querying on an index only. Either you query the entire documents ’.toArray()’ or query the index values only ’.keys()’. When using the latter, the selected index to query depends on where-clause or orderBy. If using neither of these, the primary key will be queried.